# AWS AutoScaling - how does the "Request count per target" measurement works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

When using a scaling policy in AWS fargate service, i want to scale using the "request count per target" metric.

But i am having difficulty understanding how this is determined. Is there a time period associated with the request count?

eg: requests per target per minute

Or are these concurrent requests? If it is concurrent requests, would concurrent requests be determined as requests which have been sent but not responded to?

Answer (score 3):

From docs about [RequestCountPerTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html):

> The average number of **requests received** by each target in a target group.

and

> sends its metrics in **60-second** intervals.

And it represents `average` number of requests in 1 minute intervals. I think you should [read up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/working_with_metrics.html) on how metrics work in AWS.

Comment: I don't understand the statement "Average number of requests in 1 minute". Average based on what? Are we talking about the average of concurrent/active requests?.  For example: if the load balancer get 1500 request in that minute, which is the average?

Comment: @JulianGr Average number of "requests received" by ALB.

Comment: It doesn't have sense, if i receive 1000 requests in 1 minute, which is the average? Average is used when you have a set of different values.

Comment: @JulianGr Not sure what else do you want. If you don't like how the metric works at AWS, you can use some other cloud provider or contact AWS support to ask them change the metric definition and how it works.

Comment: I am asking a question because i want to understand how it works, nothing else.

Comment: @JulianGr It works as described in AWS docs and that's what I provided in the answer.

Comment: @JulianGr You were correct in noticing that to calculate an average value, you need to have a set of different values.
When we use the request count per target measurement, AWS measures the number of requests made to each target in the group separately. Then it calculates the average requests per target. The number of requests made to each target will probably be different. If one target in our group received 12 requests and the other received 6, the average is 9 (12+6 / 2).